# What is the opposite of minor if not major?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, antonyms

We've got a name of a component in our software that's called *minor* (or, in computer English: *IsCustomerMinor*). We'd like to turn the logic around and refer to the case as the opposite, meaning not being a minor.

After some googling I've only come up with unrelated words as *magisterial* and *peremptory*, which are not really what we're looking for. The closest one was *major* but I have never heard that being used as referral to ones age.

Is the following sentence okay? If not, what work should be used instead?

> It's her decision now - she's not a minor anymore; she's a **major** as of last month, in fact.

Comment: *isCustomerOfAge*  or *isCustomerAdult*

Comment: *isCustomerNotMinor*

Comment: Just from a readability perspective, I'd be tempted to add an article into the name to make it more readable.  If it's called `isCustomerAMinor` and `isCustomerAnAdult`, it fits slightly better with the English usage.  Without the article, my mind assumes the word is describing their character.  Nathon Fillion `isAnAdult`, but I'd never say he `isAdult`.  The guy's a total kid, even at 44 (and we love him for it!)

Comment: (The difference, I believe, is that adult can be either an adjective or a noun.)

Answer (score 16):

The "opposite" of a 'minor' is an 'adult'. Or, you can say "she has reached the age of majority." For the latter see [the Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/majority), definition 2.0.

Comment: Ah, you beat me on 'age of majority' with reference. +1 :)

Comment: I can't believe how I could not have found that word. And I can't believe even more how I could actually forget it to begin with. Embarrassing...

Answer (score 5):

Another typical expression is to be [of legal age](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/legal-age?q=legal%20age).

As a side note, major is the opposite of minor, when minor is used in the meaning of "small", e.g. an item has a minor (small) flaw vs an item has a major (big, large) flaw.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to a person's age, a 'minor' is somebody who's under the age of 18 (in the USA, at least). It's a legal term that means something like 'still a child'. So the opposite of 'minor' is 'adult'.

A minor can't vote for government, doesn't usually pay income tax, and their parent can usually make legal decisions for them without their consent.

In reference to how important/severe/significant something is, the opposite is 'major'. You can have a 'minor headache' or a 'major headache'.

So - a 'minor' is a person who's under 18. A 'minor person' is somebody who's unimportant. An 'adult' is a person who's 18 or older. A 'major person' is somebody who's important.

For extra fun, 'major' is also the opposite of 'minor' in reference to western music, which has 'major' and 'minor' keys.

Answer (score -2):

If the expression of this word is about a person, I will say that the opposite of *minor* is *senior* because there is nothing like minor and major for people.  But, if it is about things like sport teams, there is minor and major, e.g. baseball leagues.

Comment: "Senior" is usually used for those who are getting on in years: perhaps they're old enough to retire, or perhaps they're just approaching that.